# After adding a gitignore, my files are flagged as "ignored" while running. Doesn't gitignore just ignore files with git?

Tags: git, visual-studio

My current understanding is that the .gitignore file is used to prevent files from being pushed to source control.  These may be sensitive files, like config files, or files that would offer no value in source control (Git).

I added a filter in .gitignore to ignore all of the classes in a folder.  In Visual Studio, these files all now have a red icon on them and when you hover over them it says "ignored".  Also, when I attempt to run my app locally, it fails because those files can't be found by the app.

Why would .gitignore be blocking the files from being part of the app at runtime?  I thought .gitignore was only used for source control?

Any idea how to 1) prevent files from being pushed to GitHub and 2) allowing those same files to happily be a part of the app?

---

Visual Studio 2019

---

Edit: this issue began when I starting pathing the .gitignore filters from project level like this:

```
/[PROJECTNAME]/[FOLDERNAME]/*
```

Comment: Visual Studio and Git are completely different things and I cannot answer any questions about VS itself, but this claim is subtly wrong: *My current understanding is that the .gitignore file is used to prevent files from being pushed to source control.* That's not the case: `.gitignore` is used to tell Git that some file should not be *added* to Git's *index* (aka *staging area*). Git creates commits from the copies of files that are in its index. So this means the files do not get *committed*. What get pushed are the commits, so if the files aren't in the commits, [continued]

Comment: [cont] ... if the files aren't in the commits, then when you push the commits, they don't carry the files along with them. But it's the *commits* that are pushed. No *files* are pushed, just *commits* (which then *contain* files, so the files come along for the ride).